# How to estimate yaw angle from magnetometer and gyroscope?

Tags: quadcopter, sensors, imu, gyroscope, filter

I'm using the MPU9250, it measures acceleration, magnetometer, gyro, etc. Complementary filter tutorial for this is [here](http://geekmomprojects.com/gyroscopes-and-accelerometers-on-a-chip), however this tutorial does not have a magnetometer and I do, thus I thought I could eliminate the gyro drift.
Seen here:

[image: serial monitor showing drift]

I've found this [post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/how-to-estimate-yaw-angle-from-tri-axis-accelerometer-and-gyroscope) already in which other users state that a magnetometer is required. However, they do not go into much detail (and because it is such an old post I didn't want to bump it).

My other complementary filters are calculated as such:

`float angle_x = alpha*gyro_angle_x + (1.0 - alpha)*accel_angle_x;`

`float angle_y = alpha * gyro_angle_y + (1.0 - alpha) * accel_angle_y;`

`angle z = yaw`

I have my local inclination angle which I have been previously told I need and I also have my magnetometer value.

My question is; How do I combine all my values into an equation for the complementary filter?

Comment: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/19166/23148 please see this post :) sparkfun as far as i know has their own arduino implementation of the Madgwick filter so you dont have to use the adafruit library...assuming you’re using an arduino

Comment: @morbo can I use that filter along with my already implemented complementary filter?

Comment: It would replace your comp filter entirely.

Comment: I have seen that the Madgwick filter has better accuracy however I’ve also seen it’s harder to implement. I have a custom arduino sketch so that’s why everything is hard coded.

Comment: Its very easy to implement if you use any of the libraries from sparkfun or adafruit :)

Comment: Should have bumped the old post! How are you currently getting your yaw estmiate angle_z? Is it computed entirely from the magnetometer data?

You can use the complementary filter to fuse the yaw estimate from the magnetometer and the one coming from gyroscope integration.